# iOS: Is it possible to use different localizable strings for the same locale code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

In iOS/Objective-C, is it possible to use different localizable strings for the same locale code?
My app has two very distinct areas and I don't want to stuff all strings from both areas into the same Localizable.strings file.

Comment: Can you provide a little more insight into the locale in question. It may be pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely - 3rd party components (should) all do this.

Instead of using `NSLocalizedString`, use `NSLocalizedStringFromTable`:

```
NSString * NSLocalizedStringFromTable(
  NSString *key,
  NSString *tableName,
  NSString *comment
)
```

Where tableName is the name of the .strings file to use.

It may be useful to create a macro for each part of your program, for example:

```
#define myComponentString(str) NSLocalizedStringFromTable(str, @"MyComponent", nil)
```

which will lookup the string in the file called "MyComponent.strings".